# Work around onClick event being fired twice on "Enter Key" press in material-ui (bug)

Tags: reactjs, events, material-ui, clojurescript, re-frame

I'm using [`cljs-react-material-ui`](https://github.com/madvas/cljs-react-material-ui) from [`re-frame`](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame).

When I click on a `flat-button`, it fires the `:on-click` event as expected. However, when I press tab to focus the button and then press return, it seems to fire the event twice. This confuses my application because its finite state machine has already moved onto the next state, in which the (repeated) event doesn't make sense.

Do I need to de-bounce this event explicitly? I would have hoped the UI framework would treat a click and a return-key press almost identically.

Answer (score 1):

It was as simple as

```clj
:on-click (fn [e] (.preventDefault e)
                  (re-frame.core/dispatch [::events/eventname]))
```

See React's [event documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

I'll update this answer when I work out whether it was the browser that sent the `click` event after the user `keydown`s Enter (or `keyup`s Space) on the button. Interestingly, `keydown`ing Meta-Enter doesn't fire the `click` event afterward. I'm sure this is all written down somewhere, I just haven't found the reference yet!

**Edit** ...aaand [here's the description of the bug](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/9439) in material-ui.